# OpenCV - Contour Lines on Gradient Every Interval

Tags: c++, opencv, gradient, contour

I'm trying to get contour lines of the following image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5zBM.png

What I'm trying to do is get lines every x amount of interval, that either close if they are entirely within the image, or are left open ended if they hit the black background.

I've tried two techniques using OpenCV and both don't quite give what I need.

The first was to use a binary threshold every x interval and then using find contours on those temporary images.  The result is close to what I want, however it wraps around the border of the image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSzL7.jpg

The second was to use an inRange at my x interval values and then find the contours.  This eliminated the wrapping problem, but created an issue where thicker sections of one color would create an enclosed poly.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNhKN.jpg

Has anyone had any experience trying to do something similar?  I'm collecting the points and creating geo-spacial polys and lines, so the other option would be to attempt some post processing, however I am concerned with the speed of that and would rather do it in OpenCV if possible.